# cant get updates in 12.04, W: Failed to fetch

Tags: updates, update-manager

I have tried many fixes from this site, and stack overflow, nothing seems to work. I have edited and/or replaced `/etc/apt/sources.list` many times, often adding "old releases" where appropriate to the urls. I have generated new sources.list online, and with the gui. No matter what, the common error messages after apt-get update:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse armhf Packages                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Fetched 5,013 kB in 3s (1,467 kB/s)
```

Now when I try to use the software center gui to edit the sources list it claims I have a connectivity problem, which is not true. And    sudo apt-get update     still has a lot of 404 errors

Comment: `armhf`? You should be using `ports.ubuntu.com`, not `old-releases.ubuntu.com` (12.04 isn't EOL yet) or `<cc>.archive.ubuntu.com` (which only support `amd64` and `i386`).

Comment: that didnt help much, a few updates happened though.